# Using the Google Calendar API. Is there any way to print out the API response code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, rest, google-calendar-api

I'm currently working on a project that uses the Google Calendar API. I would like the program that I'm creating to print out a "Success" when it successfully connects to the API or a "Failed" when it does not. Also, wondering if there's any way to specifically print out the API response code?

Answer (score 1):

Have you reviewed this [Google Calendar API tutorial for Python](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python)?

From the snippet below, you should check for errors/exceptions when generating credentials and  instantiating the client.  I have marked them as TODO #1, #2, and #3.

Please refer to the example for additional context.  Good luck!

```
def main():
"""Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.
Prints the start and name of the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
"""
creds = None
# The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())  # TODO #1: Add exception handling here (and really the entire block) to capture authentication/authorization issues
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)

service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)  # TODO #2: Add exception handling here to capture client side issues

# Call the Calendar API
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC time
print('Getting the upcoming 10 events')

# TODO #3: Add exception handling here in the actual API call
events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                    maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                    orderBy='startTime').execute()
events = events_result.get('items', [])
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment! I have looked at this quickstart.py and am working with it. 

Can you give me an example of exception handling. I'm currently trying the following:

try:

        service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    except Exception:
        print("Client side issues")